# Unofficial iText 4.2.1: Purely created magenta color contains 44% of yellow

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Following problem: I draw a magenta line on a pdf document. Before that I create a new color object like:

```
CMYKColor magentaColor = new CMYKColor(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
```

Then I set this color for the PDFContentByte like:

```
PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
cb.setColorStroke(magentaColor);
```

with pdfWriter being given the constructor as a parameter to create an instance of a class I use the PDFDirectContent in. Then I use PDFContentByte#moveTo() and PDFContentByte#lineTo() methods to draw my line.
What I can not understand is why the line color on the pdf document is not 100% magenta but contains around 44% yellow. [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=11597823479980610034) you can find the pdf with the described line(s).

Comment: I see that you are using an unofficial version of iText. iText 4.2.0 was released by a third party unknown to iText Group. It's a "gork", a fork of which God Only Really Knows what's inside. Use it at your own risk and don't expect any help if something goes wrong. Read http://itextpdf.com/maven-update-problem-with-itext-4.2.2 for more info about 4.2.0.

Comment: By the way, I looked inside the PDF and it's not *around 44%*, it's *exactly* 44%. I see this in the content stream: `0 1 0.44 0 K`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I know that we are using a "gork" version of iText, but this was the decision of the higher positioned people in the company so I have to use this one. What I still can not understand is where and more interesting WHY the value given to the constructor of CMYKColor is being overwritten and gets 44%(!) of yellow...

Comment: As I said: God Only Really Knows. Maybe you should talk to the lesser gods to find out if they can be convinced to use an official version.

Comment: @Bruno: so, just to be totally clear on this: that same line of code should insert that exact color with an official version? No way it could have been adjusted by some intervening Helpful™ color management system?

Comment: @ArthurEirich Your company, would that be Flyeralarm in Wuerzburg, Germany? Who also have a Belgian office at Koloniënstraat 11, Brussels?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse As you may look in my profile, yes. Why does it matter?

Comment: @Jongware I don't know which code the OP is using, but in his PDF, I see `0 1 0.44 0 K`, whereas when I create a simple example using the same `CMYKColor`, I see `0 1 0 0 K`. I can post an answer with my POC.

Comment: @ArthurEirich I have asked our German sales rep to contact your management so that they allow you to work with the official version of iText instead of forcing you to use a "malware" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a Colormanagement Issue. When drawing a 100% magenta line CMYK(0,100,0,0) and convert the document to RGB back and forth the line is no longer 100% magenta only.

The reason for this is, RGB (and [CIELab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space)) both are 3dimensional color spaces whereas CMYK has 4 dimensions. Only three dimensions are needed in order to describe the visual impression  of a color.

Using the 4th dimensions in CMYK you are able to manage the configuration of your color. Whereas RGB and CIELab provide just ONE configuration for a specific color, CMYK provides an amount of configurations for describing one and the same visual impression.

For example, the color code for a 30% grey is RGB(74,74,75). Using CMYK you can describe one and the same point with CMYK(0,0,0,30) (black only) or CMYK(25,18,17,0) (without black). Both CMYK Configurations have one and the same
visual impression. This behavior is used for UCR (Under Color Removal) and GCR (Grey Component Replacement).

So, please ensure that your PDF is not being converted unnecessarily to RGB (or any other color space) back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [DrawingLines](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/graphics/drawing-lines) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    CMYKColor magentaColor = new CMYKColor(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    canvas.setColorStroke(magentaColor);
    canvas.moveTo(36, 36);
    canvas.lineTo(36, 806);
    canvas.lineTo(559, 36);
    canvas.lineTo(559, 806);
    canvas.closePathStroke();
    document.close();
}
```

It results in the file [draw_lines.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/graphics/cmp_draw_lines.pdf):

[image]

The color is magenta only:

[image]

When I look at your PDF, I see a different value:

[image]

Where I expect `0 1 0 0 K`, I see `0 1 0.44 0 K`. I also see that you are using something that is marked `/ITXT: 4.2.0`. The prefix `ITXT` was registered at ISO by iText Group NV. Only iText Group is allowed to use this prefix in its software. You are using software with version number 4.2.0. iText Group NV has never released iText 4.2.0. It is a rogue version.

Please share this with the people who forced you to use this unofficial version and tell them that they should upgrade.